# Group by names desc - get last entered values for a grouped name

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have an table like that:

```
id | name | v (lvl)
11 | Jane | 6
12 | John | 5
13 | Jane | 6
14 | John | 5
15 | Jane | 7
16 | Jane | 5
```

In my autocomplete form now id like to group the names but get the last value (value with biggest id). In the example above would be

```
Jane | 5
```

I tried with combinations like distinct, group by, order by. But im always get

```
Jane | 6
```

or grouped like this and reversed:

```
Jane | 6 
Jane | 7 
Jane | 5
```

I would need something like this:

```
SELECT name,lvl FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT name, lvl FROM pora WHERE name LIKE 'Jane' ORDER BY lvl DESC
)
GROUP BY name
```

EDIT: I won't get the highest lvl, i want get the lvl of the highest id, grouped by name. Thats all. My example above would be the best explanation what i like to get.
In the inner query i change the order to DESC for all and in the outer i group it by names. But i get an error for this.

**EDIT 2** I finally did at my own. The correct solution (i was already close):

```
SELECT a.name, a.lvl FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT name, lvl FROM pora WHERE name LIKE 'Jane' ORDER BY id DESC
)as a
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: How you know who is the latest value with biggest id? You say `Jane | 5` Why? ? Are there more names or just want the result from `Jane` ?

Comment: I ordered the example above with id ASC ;D. I can add the ids if you like. EDIT Yes in the database are more names but in this query i only would have this name.

Comment: Yes please, still you need to explain the logic. I dont know why you choose Jane 5

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which is liable to prove problematic in due course.

Comment: `... order by id desc limit 1` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Would work but there are more names wich can be similar and if its only showing 1 that will be a problem.

Comment: @delato468 Your question request a single result, how is that a problem now?

Comment: can you show us example, when you expect more than 1 row ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no i excpect 1 row for lvl but not 1 row for names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thats not the same

Comment: Yes it is. Check Brian L Cartwright answer. In your case the @N is 1

Comment: @OtoShavadze I shared an example in Juan Carlos answer.

Comment: Your `EDIT 2` may work but is only because a internal setup of MySQL. I wouldnt recomend that solution. You should check the duplicated answer I provide.

Comment: For all others wich searching for the same, Juan is talking about https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187418/3844973 this. But in my opinion it's not right. If @JuanCarlosOropeza could adjust it for the example above i can try it and look if it's right. Else don't watch at the dublicate.

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` without `%` is just `=`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name = 'Jane'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But because you mention autocomplete functionality you should use:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'Jane%'
```

Comment: Limit is not working because if 2 names can be very similar. For example blablabla1 and blablabla2. If im writing now blabla then i can see only 1 name until i finish the full name.

Comment: That wasnt what you ask :(

Comment: Yeah but i said it's a autocomplete form, it's normal there are more names that can be similar.

Comment: You need to learn how to ask a proper question so you get better answers. Otherwise we waste time trying to guess what is what you want.  Please check the link I post.

Comment: I understand the question now, but only because read all the comment. But if you read  the text question there is nothing showing you want the last result for each name. I'm just saying is your job make sure the question has all the details.

Comment: It's in the question... I can repeat for you. "the last value (value with biggest id)" and i did an example "Jane | 5"

Comment: That indicate a single result, not multiple result :(

Comment: Yeah but we talking about names. It doesn't need much entrys to get 2 similar names like Jane doe and Jane smith. It's important to calculate that before things like that destorys the autocomplete function. But i gave to all of you an upvote because your help ;D. Thanks and yes im sorry if not everything were clear, but it's hard for me to ask in another language i didn't learnd well.

Answer (score 2):

To have the latest, you need to have a field `dateAdded` which stores the date you ran the insert command.

Following which, you use `MAX(dateAdded)` to get the latest `ID` (since, as you mentioned, it may decrease as well)

**UPDATE:**

if `ID` doesn't decrease, you can always use `MAX(ID)`

```
SELECT MAX(id), v from tablename where name = 'Jane'
```

**UPDATE:**

This has been tested: 
`SELECT ID, v from tableName where ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) as ID from tableName where name like '%Jane%')`

Comment: The id wont decrease.

Comment: @delato468 if ID doesn't decrease, you can always use MAX(ID)

Comment: Like that i will get the highest id but not the associated vale (lvl)

Comment: @delato468
Sir, Can you please post the result of this query,
 `SELECT MAX(id), v from tablename where name like '%Jane%'` ?

Comment: The result of your sql would be 16 | Jane | 6. Correct would be 16 | Jane | 5

Comment: I checked: This works:
`SELECT ID, v from tableName where ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) as ID from tableName where name like '%Jane%') `

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query (h/t @lamak)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name
                                  ORDER BY [id] DESC)
    FROM poro
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but like that i will always get the highest lvl in the example above "jane | 7", but i would like to get "Jane | 5"

Comment: Because the values can change up and down and i want have always the latest in my autocomplete.

Comment: @delato468 what do you want to pull, the highest lvl number? Or how do you know what's the latest?

Comment: Sorry for missleading, each column has an id and i want have always the result with the highest id.

Comment: Can you provide sample data of how your table looks?

Comment: @kazzi no i still get Jane | 6 like that

Comment: You might be using T-SQL then. Just use MAX() in lvl as well.

Comment: That dont work as expected. Your Max(id) may be different to the Max(lvl)

Comment: So? It will still work. You're just doing that to group the statement. You can use Min() to

Comment: @kazzi You get the highest id but not the associated lvl. The lvl will be that from the first row.

Comment: @delato468 yeah, I'm not a big fan of T-SQL. I gave it one more edit, check it out.

Comment: @kazzi If you group lvl too, then you will get: 11 | Jane | 6, 15 | Jane | 7, 16 | Jane | 5

Comment: @delato468 this is the latest update that should work for you ^